# Manifest parsing error when trying to test app in Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

From https://dev.teams.microsoft.com/, whenever I click "Preview in Teams", it shows an error in Teams with these details copied to the clipboard: "Error while reading manifest.json". If I download the app package and "upload a custom app" I get the same error. What can I do to resolve this? If I remove the messaging extension configuration, it works but I configured that part in their app and that's what I want to build.

This is my manifest file:

```
{
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.11/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
"version": "1.0.0",
"manifestVersion": "1.11",
"id": "3fXXXX",
"packageName": "com.package.name",
"name": {
    "short": "Domo Integration",
    "full": ""
},
"developer": {
    "name": "Domo Inc.",
    "mpnId": "",
    "websiteUrl": "https://www.domo.com",
    "privacyUrl": "https://www.domo.com/company/privacy-policy",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.domo.com/company/service-terms"
},
"description": {
    "short": "short",
    "full": "full"
},
"icons": {
    "outline": "outline.png",
    "color": "color.png"
},
"accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
"composeExtensions": [
    {
        "botId": "deXXXXXXXX",
        "commands": [],
        "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
        "messageHandlers": [
            {
                "type": "link",
                "value": {
                    "domains": [
                        "*.domo.com"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
],
"validDomains": [
    "*.domo.com"
]
```

}

Comment: Could you please share the manifest?

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT I updated my question to include my manifest.json.

Answer (score 0):

@ccnokes In order to use messaging extension in your bot, you need to provide at least one command. `commands` is required property in composeExtension - see [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema#composeextensions).

I was also getting the same error when tried with your manifest but after adding commands it worked totally fine.

Comment: yay that "worked" in the sense that I can preview it in Teams but it's not sending my bot any unfurling requests. It sent a type: conversationUpdate and that's it. Any ideas on that?

Comment: After installation of the bot, whenever you will put the URL in compose  box that is there in messageHandlers then you will get the unfurl request.